# detect small object usimg imcontour matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to identify Nevi within a picture. I tried to use the imcontour function and from there determine the size of the mole/nevus, its shape and color. The problem is that I can not understand what the function gives me and how to advance from that point. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: It would return a `list` comprising of all the points present in the contour identified

Comment: Uploading the image and mentioning what to find would help.....

Comment: which part of https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imcontour.html did you not understand?

Comment: As @JeruLuke suggested uploading the image. Please also add the code you have already achieved, so we can know what have you done so far in coding.

Comment: I dont have big code becuse I'm new at matlab and I dont to where to start. the only thing that I did is to read image and call imconutour function

Comment: `imcontour` creates a contour plot of a gray-scale image, i.e. connecting all points with the same intensity value. I think you are more interested in some kind of _blob detection_. Thresholding your image and using [`regionprops`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) to find the properties of the different regions may be an easy solution.